# Has the notion of an addonym - or a word with a similar meaning - been described in the English language before?

Tags: neologisms, academia, reference

**Background**

In the near future, I am planning on publishing my first scientific article as a PhD candidate. My surname is very common in countries like Germany and Austria, and my first name is quite popular as well.

Therefore, I hope to publish the paper with an added, invented middle name. The idea is that this makes me more easy to find in certain search engines, and makes my academic contributions more recognizable to other research. My full academic name would be "Max Lonysa Muller".

I've asked about this idea on Academia Stack Exchange -- a link can be found [over here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/195083/is-it-a-good-idea-to-add-an-invented-middle-name-on-arxiv-and-other-repositories). Respondents generally seemed positive towards the idea of adding such an invented middle name.

I was wondering whether other scientists or philosophers have published articles with such an added, invented name. However, I haven't been able to find any -- in part due to the fact that I don't know what such added names are called. I suppose an "addonym" could be a good way to describe the concept. It comes from the Latin word "addere" -- which means "to add".

> **Question**: is there a word for the concept of adding an invented name to one's actual name?

Comment: You could call it a 'nickname' since it isn't your real name. For example the former snooker player Alex "Hurricane" Higgins.

Comment: Or you could become Maxx Muller.

Comment: @WeatherVane haha wow, pretty sad you're attacking people on the internet you don't know. I was asking about this concept because I want to write a wikipedia article on it, and because I am genuinely interested in learning about this notion. Moreover, the most highly upvoted answer also stated that adding an inventing name might be very helpful to make one's name more googleable, so your summary of Arno's answer is incorrect at best, and disingenuous at worst

Comment: Yet you haven't accepted that answer.

Comment: @WeatherVane It really isn't any of your business whether I accept answers to questions I pose on another forum. I also ask you to refrain from posting any further comments to this question -- your negativity isn't appreciated whatsoever

Comment: Most of the answers suggest ORCID as the way to go, generally point out drawbacks to not using your actual full name, and few seem to be "positive towards the idea of adding such an invented middle name", except one, by using deedpoll.

Comment: Wouldn’t it simply be called *adopting a pseudonym* or *adopting a pen name*, even if you’re only modifying part of your name? Related, maybe: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/8603/if-i-publish-under-a-pseudonym-can-i-still-take-credit-for-my-work. Also search e.g. `using a pseudonym in academic authorship`

Comment: JK Rowling and George RR Martin both invented a middle initial to sound better; so similar things are not uncommon, although I don't know a name for it.

Comment: @StuartF Thank you, this is the type of constructive response I'm looking for

Comment: Presumably you are aware that _Lonysa_ looks like a feminine name to English readers?

Comment: @KateBunting I was under the impression it would come across as androgynous, but I can imagine it seems feminine because it ends with an *a* (and it sounds a bit like Lisa). I've noticed some men have - in my opinion, beautiful - feminine surnames, like Alexander Luria, Louis-Ferdinand Céline, Pierre Nora, and Giuseppe Lauricella. Also: Voltaire's birth name was Francois Marie Arouet.However, I'm not very concerned about gender misunderstandings, as my first name also included - which is recognizably masculine

Comment: Yes, I know some European Catholics use their version of 'Mary' as a man's middle name (e.g. also Rainer Maria Rilke).

Comment: Surnames are not generally interpreted as gendered in English, since they're inherited the same way by both sons and daughters (unlike Russian, for example, where the suffix is "-ov" for boys and "-ova" for girls). We only expect assigned names to conform to the person's gender.